# set webview to scroll down to a particular point

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webview, titanium

Hi I was wondering if there's anyway when loading a webview in titanium to skip down to a particular portion of a page. I thought it would be called an anchorpoint but that property didn't do anything for me. Could I inject some html or what is the best way to do this. I'll need it for Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should include a function at JS code of WebView added.

So, use:

```
webViewNew.addEventListener('load', function(){
    webViewNew.evalJS('functionScroll()');
});
```

Use this reference for [JS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

This code execute function when the webview is loaded (DOM).

Comment: Hi thank you very much for the response. I understood I would have to add some listener to the webview and call a function to do the scrolling, but it's the actual scrolling part I don't know how to do. The code you pointed me to seems to be jQuery, however I am working with Titanium and do not know how to scroll in that environment

Comment: Titanium does not have control over WebView content, so you can not scroll from Titanium Code. You must do scroll from HTML with JavaScript function (jQuery, JavaScript or any)

Comment: but can you not inject html into a webview? I think I did something like this before. But when I inject html, I can't use jQuery within titanium, just regular js. Or at least I think so??

Comment: something like this: WebView.addEventListener('load', function onLoad(e) {
  WebView.setHtml('something to set the scroll">'+ originalWebView.html);
  WebView.reload();
  WebView.removeEventListener('load', onLoad);
});

Comment: You should have scroll code in originalWebView.html due to HTML headers and parse HTML code. Example: blablabla... <html></html> For inject js frameworks or something, you should have all code inside html code, because Titanium think that is a Titanium JS not JS Plain File (bug Android).

Comment: Ok so it's not doable from titanium and I need to request the scroll from the web developer?

Comment: Yes. [An example](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/46431/detecting-scroll-on-a-webview)